# PWA should only render as mobile mode

Tags: android, html, progressive-web-apps

Just faced with an interesting issue.

On my PWA running on Android if I set Desktop mode, on the Chrome browser, my PWA will show in Desktop mode.

[image]

On the left is the mobile mode, on the right is the same PWA with Desktop mode activated on Chrome.

Is there a way to force the PWA to always show as mobile? Or ignore this setting?

I do not even know if I can/should tackle this issue from the Android TWA side or from the HTML side.

Any ideais?

Thank you so much.